# TypeScript Multiple files same namespace

Tags: typescript

i'm working on a personal project with Typescript.

To have a nice code and expendable code i want to split my code like that => One class One file, using namespace or module, i didnt see the difference !

But how can i call one file et be able to select all class which are inside this namespace ?

I had take a look into StackOverflow database but i haven't found anything !

For example:

```
// FileOne.ts
namespace Controllers {
  export class A {}
}

// FileTwo.ts
namespace Controllers {
  export class B {}
}

// index.ts
namespace App {
  constructor() {
    new Controllers.B();
    new Controllers.A();
  }
}
```

So if you have an idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespaces are built for that, you just need to reference all the files you need into your index.ts.

Typescript transpiler & Visual Studio Code are build in TypeScript, So you can have a look into the code in GitHub ( [TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript) | [VSCode](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) ), you will learn a lot ;)

Comment: Ok but have is the point ! If i use a namespace it's because i don't want to import all files everytime ! and when i reference my files into my index.ts i have an error " <file> is not a module " ...

Comment: You need to import them or reference them... Otherwhise how he can know that the file exist... When you develop in C# or Java you need using or import, for typescript it's the same